# What does it mean to put a function into 'setState()' parameter in React-hook method?

Tags: react-hooks

First of all, please understand that I'm not good at English.

I am studying react-hook.
I am looking at an example code, and the factors(?) is declared in the function component as follows.

```
const lottoNumbers = useMemo(() => getWinNumbers(), []);
const [winNumbers, setWinNumbers] = useState(lottoNumbers);
const [winBalls, setWinBalls] = useState([]);
```

and `setWinballs` were used as follows.

```
    for (let i = 0; i < winNumbers.length - 1; i++) {
      timeouts.current[i] = setTimeout(() => {
        setWinBalls((prevBalls) => [...prevBalls, winNumbers[i]]);  <--------
      }, (i + 1) * 1000);
```

What does '`setWinBalls((prevBalls) => [...prevBalls, winNumbers[i]])`' mean here?

I didn't know that the 'set' function could have a function parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The function `setWinBalls()` is using an arrow function which returns an object. [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) has been used inside the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which simply adds the current winNumber which is `winNumbers[i]` to the array and stores the updated array into another variable.

```
//example to understand what spread syntax does
var exampleArray = [1, 2, 3];
exampleArray = [...exampleArray, 4];
//exampleArray will be [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now let us try and understand what this arrow function is doing. The `for` loop can be written this way:

```
 for (let i = 0; i < winNumbers.length - 1; i++) {
      timeouts.current[i] = setTimeout(() => {
        var updatedBalls = (prevBalls) => [...prevBalls, winNumbers[i]];
        //winNumbers[i] will be added to the end to prevBalls array and updated array will be stored in updatedBalls

        setWinBalls(updatedBalls);
      }, (i + 1) * 1000);
```

Hope the code is clear to you now.